# How do I make <div> stretch vertically with the amount of content?

Tags: css, height

I have a vertical div with five little divs inside. Now, I want the first two and the last two to have specific heights, and the one in the middle to be changeable, depending on the amount of content inside of it. Also, there should probably be a minimum height to the entire div, so it can fit the page nicely, and the bottom two divs are supposed to be fixed to the bottom of the page. I am only allowed to use CSS. Since I don't have any code for this, let's say those four fixed divs have the height of 100px, and they are named #one, #two, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use:

```
.two {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cLd2ybv/

Comment: This would work, the only problem is that I'm using flexbox elements for the entire website (that's divided in divs), so this doesn't apply. I have tried justify-content, but that doesn't work either. If I use flex-basis: auto for the middle element, I can't define the minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, all you have to do is set the elements

```
display:block;
```

here's an example:

```css
#container{
 border:1px solid black;
}
.element{
 display: block;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 margin:0px;
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
 </div>
```